# consul-api-gateway load balancer always shows registered target un healthy in aws eks environment

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, amazon-eks, api-gateway, consul

I am trying to create a consul-api-gateway (Gateway) resource with HttpRoute for keycloak service in aws eks cluster. I am configuring in a way that the api-gateway and keycloak service are running in different namespaces. But when consul-api-gateway resource created with below deployment yaml, it is creating aws load balancer with the registered target showing as unhealthy. Not sure what makes this as unhealthy always.

Consul-server-and-ui-deployment.yaml

```
---
global:
  name: consul  
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: "***"
  image: /hashicorp/consul:1.12.0
  imageEnvoy: /envoyproxy/envoy:v1.22.2
  imageK8S: /hashicorp/consul-k8s-control-plane:0.44.0
  metrics:
    enabled: true
server:
  replicas: 3
  bootstrapExpect: 3
  extraLabels:
    tags.datadoghq.com/source: consul
    tags.datadoghq.com/service: consul-server
  annotations: |
    "tags.datadoghq.com/source":                              "consul"
    "tags.datadoghq.com/service":                             "consul-server"
  updatePartitions: 3
  disruptionBudget:
    maxUnavailable: 1
  tolerations: >
    -
    key:                                                    "taint_for_consul_xor_vault"
      operator:                                               "Equal"
      value:                                                  "true"
      effect:                                                 "NoSchedule"
  nodeSelector: |
    'eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType':                         'ON_DEMAND'
    'purpose':                                                'consul-server'
  storage: 50G
  priorityClassName: high-priority
client:
  enabled: true
  grpc: true
  exposeGossipPorts: false
  priorityClassName: high-priority
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 1G
      cpu: "1"
    limits:
      memory: 1G
      cpu: "1"
  healthChecks:
    enabled: true
  hostNetwork: false
  extraConfig: |
    {
      "advertise_reconnect_timeout":                          "15m",
      "limits":                                               {
        "http_max_conns_per_client":                          -1
      }
    }
  extraLabels:
    tags.datadoghq.com/source: consul
    tags.datadoghq.com/service: consul-client
  annotations: |
    "tags.datadoghq.com/source":                              "consul"
    "tags.datadoghq.com/service":                             "consul-client"
  updateStrategy: |
    type:                                                     RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable:                                         1
ui:
  enabled: true
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    additionalSpec: "'ports': [{'name': 'http', 'protocol': 'TCP', 'port': 8500,
      'targetPort': 8500}, {'name': 'https', 'protocol': 'TCP', 'port': 8501,
      'targetPort': 8501}]"
    annotations: |
      'service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme':  'internal'
      'service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type':    'nlb-ip'
controller:
  enabled: true
prometheus:
  enabled: true
grafana:
  enabled: true
terminatingGateways:
  enabled: true
  priorityClassName: high-priority
  defaults:
    replicas: 2
apiGateway:
  enabled: true
  image: /hashicorp/consul-api-gateway:0.3.0
  controller:
    replicas: 2
    priorityClassName: high-priority
connectInject:
  enabled: true
  priorityClassName: high-priority
  transparentProxy:
    defaultEnabled: true
  default: false
syncCatalog:
  enabled: true
  priorityClassName: high-priority
  default: false
  toConsul: true
  toK8S: false
```

Consul-api-gateway-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion:         api-gateway.consul.hashicorp.com/v1alpha1
kind:               GatewayClassConfig
metadata:
  name:             consul-common-gateway-class-config
spec:
  logLevel:         'info'  
  copyAnnotations:
    service:
      - service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme
      - service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type
  consul:
    scheme:         'http'
    ports:
      http:         8500
      grpc:         8502
  serviceType:      LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion:         gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind:               GatewayClass
metadata:
  name:             consul-common-gateway-class
spec:
  controllerName:   'hashicorp.com/consul-api-gateway-controller'
  parametersRef:
    group:          api-gateway.consul.hashicorp.com
    kind:           GatewayClassConfig
    name:           consul-common-gateway-class-config
---
apiVersion:                                                 gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind:                                                       Gateway
metadata:
  name:                                                     common-api-gateway
  annotations:
     'service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme':  'internal'
     'service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type':    'nlb-ip'           
spec:
  gatewayClassName:                                         consul-common-gateway-class
  listeners:  
  - protocol:                                               HTTP
    port:                                                   80
    name:                                                   http
    allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from:                                               All
```

HttpRoute-keycloak-deployment.yaml

```
---
apiVersion:       gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind:             HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name:           gateway-keycloak-route
  namespace:      app-ns
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name:         common-api-gateway
    namespace:    consul
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        type:     PathPrefix
        value:    /auth
    backendRefs:
    - kind:       Service
      name:       keycloak
      port:       80
      namespace:  app-ns
---
apiVersion:       gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind:             ReferencePolicy
metadata:
  name:           reference-policy-keycloak
spec:
  from:
    - group:      gateway.networking.k8s.io
      kind:       HTTPRoute
      namespace:  app-ns
  to:
    - group:      ""
      kind:       Service
      name:       keycloak
```

I wanted api-gateway load balancer running in aws eks to be with healthy registered targets and wanted to run Keycloak service have proper routes to api-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a very similar issue today, and spend hours trying to figure it out.
I also had a very similar setup with a Consul API Gateway behind an internal AWS load balancer.

What solved it for me, was changing the load balancer type from ip to instance.
In my case , I was using the [AWS Load balancer controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html), which seems to be the [recommended way to go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html).
So, I defined the annotations on Gateway like this like this:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "external"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internal"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "instance"
```

And, of course, adding the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type` to the list of annotations to copy.

If you don't wish to install it, I think you can simply change the value of
`'service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type` from `'nlb-ip'` to `'nlb'`. I haven't tested it, but it should be the equivalent setting for the built-in kubernetes load balancer controller.

Hope this helps!

Also I have a few suggestion which are probably not related to the issue but might help you maintain a cleaner code.
You should change the deprecated `ReferencePolicy` object to a [`ReferenceGrant`](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/api-types/referencegrant/).
In addition, you might not need to define a custom `GatewayClass` and `GatewayClassConfig`, since you can control many of the settings of the load balancer through the `values.yaml` file you use to deploy consul, making your configuration shorter and simpler.
For example, this is the relevant part from my file

```
apiGateway:
  enabled: true
  image: "hashicorp/consul-api-gateway:0.5.1"
  # Configuration settings for the default GatewayClass which consul will use.
  managedGatewayClass:
    serviceType: LoadBalancer
    copyAnnotations:
      service:
        annotations: |
          - service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type
          - service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme
          - service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type
```

And then in the `Gateway` I just set `gatewayClassName: consul-api-gateway` which is the default class.

Comment: Thank you Alex. This works good. did you enabled TLS in your config, if yes can you post the config required